# react does not recognize the objects as parameters

Tags: reactjs, object

I copy and paste the examples I find (including the imports) but it doesn't recognize the objects. Something is missing in the configuration.

[image]
[image]

However this does work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
```

Imports for these 2 examples:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import NativeSelect from '@material-ui/core/NativeSelect';
```

Example copied and pasted: [demo.tsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/vl89x?file=/demo.tsx:0-7641)

My app.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../css/app.css';
import NativeSelects from './components/NativeSelects';
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

ReactDOM.render(<Router><NativeSelects /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I copy the content of the demo.tsx file and copy it to a NativeSelect.js

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code that you copied is in typescript, you are probably using just javascript

Comment: You're right. I don't have typescript enabled in the project and that's why those warnings come out. Thank you!